# Binding c# Property to a different Property on the SAME control

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding

Good Morning, 
I need to make the label below to where the Tag property will be the same as the content.

Basically If the content is "this label's content" then the Tag property should be "this label's content" as well.
I have tried quite a few things however this is my most recent attempt:

```
 <Label x:Name="label" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=ColorForBGG}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=x.Content}"/>
```

Comment: What's with the `x.`? Why not just `Path=Content`?

Comment: @nvoigt that helped a lot, thank you. unsure why i was trying to use x. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this directly using the Element-

```
<Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=ColorForBGG}" Margin="62,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="{Binding Content, ElementName=label}"/>
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that i cannot assign the element an ID in my scenario, I am trying to do this for 400+ elements and it is not feasible to use ids.